# question related to linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $f$ and $g$ be non-
zero linear functionals on $V$. Assume that $ker(f)$ is contained in  $ker(g)$. Which of the following statements are true?

a. $ker(f) = ker(g)$

b. $f = ag$ for some real number  $a$ not equal to $0$

c. The linear map $A : V \rightarrow  \mathbb R^2$ defined by
$Ax = (f(x),g(x))$ for all $x \in V$ , is onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $T:V\to W$ is a linear map, the **rank** and **nullity** of $T$ are defined as
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rk}{rk}\rk T =\dim\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}\im T \qquad
\DeclareMathOperator{nul}{nul}\nul T =\dim\ker T
$$
respectively. Also recall that the **rank-nullity theorem** states that
$$
\rk T+\nul T=\dim V
$$

You are given two linear maps $f,g:V\to\Bbb R$ such that
$$
\ker f\subseteq\ker g\tag{1}
$$

Note that $\rk f>0$ since $f$ is nonzero. Since $\im f$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$  and $\dim\Bbb R=1$ it follows that $$\rk f=1\tag{2}$$ Similarly $$\rk g=1\tag{3}$$

Now, the rank-nullity theorem implies
$$
\rk f+\nul f=\rk g+\nul g\tag{4}
$$
Combining (2), (3), and (4) gives 
$$
\nul f=\nul g\tag{5}
$$
Finally, (1) and (5) imply $\ker f=\ker g$. This proves (a) in the affirmative.

Can you construct a few examples to test the validity of (b)? Solving (c) should be simple once you understand the above proof of (a).